# Add,Remove Dynamic rows with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have done with adding and removing dynamic rows in html, jquery.

[jsfiddle.net/gansai/p5QwC/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/gansai/p5QwC/1/)

HTML:

```
<form action="grading.php" method="post">               
<table width="100%" id="tableRealizzazione">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th style="padding:12px;text-align:center;">Serial No</th>
        <th style="padding:12px;text-align:center;">Personale</th>
        <th style="padding:12px;text-align:center;">Percentage</th>
        <th style="padding:12px;text-align:center;">Marketing point</th>
        <th style="padding:12px;text-align:center;">Add/Remove</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="serial[]"  class="add increment" value="1">
        </td>
        <td style="padding:12px;">
            <input type="text" value="" name="Personale[]">
        </td>
        <td style="padding:12px;">
            <input type="text" name="from[]" size="5%"> -
            <input type="text" name="to[]" size="5%"> %
        </td>
        <td style="padding:12px;">
            <input type="text" class="totaliCostiGestione" name="marketpt[]">
        </td>
        <td style="padding:12px;">
            <input type="text" name="programid[]" class="add" value="34" size="10%">
        </td>
        <td style="padding:12px;">
            <input type="button" class="addnew add" value="+" />
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </td>
    </tr>                     
</table>
```

​

jQuery:

```
    $('.addnew').live('click', function(){
var thisRow = $(this).parent().parent();
newRow = thisRow.clone(true).insertAfter(thisRow);
newRow.find('input:not(.add)').val("");

$(this).removeClass('addnew').addClass('remove');
    $(this).val("-");
    newRow.find('input.increment').val(parseInt(thisRow.find('input.increment').val())+1);
});

$('.remove').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

​
​
But I want add/remove actions to the same button. Instead of appearing remove icon to the previous row.

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Can you give more explanation please? Not too clear what you want.

Comment: I want to add,remove dynamic rows and this was working code, right now my jquery works like add/remove rows for separate icons, but I want add/remove actions to the same button            http://jsfiddle.net/DjddU/

Comment: What buttons are you talking about? The buttons on the side of your "rows" in the link you provided are add/remove buttons. If you click on a "+" button, it will add a row, and this "+" button will change to a "-" button, allowing you to remove a row. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, but + icon and - icon. When I click first time '+'icon should work and add a new row. And when I click '-' icon i want in the same row only but not to the previous row

Comment: Yes, I updated my previuos comment. They seem to work fine!

Comment: I have edited my code along with Fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for, but let me know if it isn't.

```
    $('.addnew').live('click', function(){
    var thisRow = $(this).parent().parent();
    newRow = thisRow.clone(true).insertAfter(thisRow);
    newRow.find('input:not(.add)').val("");

    newRow.find('.addnew').removeClass('addnew').addClass('remove');
    newRow.find('.remove').val("-");
    newRow.find('input.increment').val(parseInt(thisRow.find('input.increment').val())+1);
});

$('.remove').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

This keeps the + on the first row and adds - buttons to the cloned rows.

http://jsfiddle.net/p5QwC/3/ for a working example.

**UPDATE**

Assuming you don't want the initial row to be removable, maybe this is more what you are looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/p5QwC/10/

Comment: That was the earlier code workign same, but need + and  - actions to the same row not the - to the previous row

Comment: So once a row is added, you want a + button and a - button on every row?

Comment: Like this example -  http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/designers/create-a-form-with-a-dynamic-list-of-input-elements/

Comment: Added a new jsfiddle link in the update. See if that is what you need.

Comment: " + and - should be same for each row, but right now it was  - in the previous row. The same logic i got. i think you may get idea by looking at this http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/designers/create-a-form-with-a-dynamic-list-of-input-elements/

Comment: Sorry, wasn't putting the correct jsfiddle link in (don't use it much myself). I fixed the updated link to show the changes.

Comment: Ya exactly, this logic Iam looking for, but could we make these + and - at the top of the page instead of each row. If this is ok, not forcing to come up again

Comment: Hi mookamafoob, I have one more issue with this, if you could solve, can we hide '+' for all rows except first row and '-' is working fine